# Add multiple sub-documents in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am working on a customer data loader, where customers can have multiple addresses.  If the customer is not found, I create it and add the address.  If the customer exists, I simply add the new address, like this:

```
    DBObject findCustomer = new BasicDBObject();
    findCustomer.put("email", custEmail);

    //check for existing customer
    DBObject newCustomer = customerCollection.findOne(findCustomer);

    if (newCustomer == null) {
        //INSERT    
        newCustomer = new BasicDBObject();
        newCustomer.put("firstname", firstname);
        newCustomer.put("lastname", lastname);
        newCustomer.put("email", custEmail);
        newCustomer.put("password", custData.getPassword());
        newCustomer.put("softwaretime", new Date());
    }

    DBObject newAddress = new BasicDBObject();
    City tempCity = new City();
    tempCity = addressData.getCity();

    newAddress.put("type", addressData.getType());
    newAddress.put("line1", addressData.getLine1());
    newAddress.put("line2", addressData.getLine2());
    newAddress.put("city", tempCity.getCity());
    newAddress.put("state", tempCity.getState());
    newAddress.put("postal", tempCity.getZip());
    newAddress.put("country", tempCity.getCountry());

    newCustomer.put("address", newAddress);

    customerCollection.save(newCustomer);
```

This works for new customers.  The problem is that when the customer already exists, the new address overwrites the existing address.

How can I add the new address to the customer, so that it will keep multiple addresses?

From what I've found, I should be able to accomplish this with a "push" via the shell.  But I don't see "push" as method on the BasicDBObject.

Comment: This looks dangerous - what happens when you have multiple customers with the same first name and last name?  This code is also not thread safe - if two threads are trying to create the same customer you may end up with a duplicate.  You also may have the same address pushed twice.

Comment: Good points @AsyaKamsky, I'll use email address for the search key instead.  Also, this is a single-threaded application designed for loading data into MongoDB.  If multiple (competing) threads were a possibility, how would you suggest accounting for thread safety?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that - depends on what your application logic expects/needs.  You could just make email unique and then the second insert attempt will fail, but your application will need to expect that and recover.  You could use Java concurrency, but if it's just multiple copies of address that's the issue you can use $addToSet instead of $push and then you won't end up adding an address that's already on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic can be much simpler, as it turns out.  You don't need to fetch customer by "email" (I'm assuming that this is your unique identifying key for Customer) just update.

```
findCustomer.put("email", custEmail); // search query for the customer email

// construct your newAddress object the same way you already are

BasicDBObject custMod = new BasicDBObject();
custMod.put("$addToSet", newAddress);
customerCollection.update(findCustomer, custMod, true /* upsert */, false /* multi */ );
```

Big problem with the way you have your logic now is it won't work multi-threaded.   You can check for customer, and it won't be there.  While you are constructing the object to insert it, another thread is already doing it.  Since address object is an array rather than a single field, using $addToSet will add to the array if it exists, but if it's creating a new customer, then it will create address as an array.

Answer (score 2):

You want address to be a list of addresses instead of a single address document. So for new customers you want to have:

```
newCustomer.put("addresses", [newAddress])
customerCollection.save(newCustomer)
```

And for existing customers you want

```
customerCollection.update(newCustomer, {$push: {"addresses": newAddress}})
```

*sorry, I don't know the java API, so you'll have to adapt the code above to create the appropriate objects*

Comment: $push is not correct for existing customer unless you check that this address record doesn't exist (and if even if you do it wouldn't be safe in multithreaded set-up.  Use $addToSet instead - it will only add if it's not already there, $push adds unconditionally).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky would you happen to know the Java syntax for doing this?

Comment: yes.  since I don't think this answer is correct, I will post it in a separate answer.