# Java mongoDB Driver Replace Or Insert in Array

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57c73d28b61b482f5884a729"),
"complete" : true,
"han" : "12345-678",
"matchingHan" : "12345678",
"availabilities" : [
    {
        "size_a" : "45",
        "size_b" : "10.5",
        "size_c" : "11.5",
        "available" : true,
        "shop_id" : "1"
    },
    {
        "size_a" : "46",
        "size_b" : "11",
        "size_c" : "12",
        "available" : false,
        "shop_id" : "1"
    },
    {
        "size_a" : "45",
        "size_b" : "10.5",
        "size_c" : "11.5",
        "available" : true,
        "shop_id" : "2"
    },
]
}
```

**This is my question:**
How can I update or insert to the availabilities Array. If there is an document with size_a = 45 with shop_id 1, I would like to update the available status. If there is not that document, I would like to insert a new document. I found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471553/add-multiple-sub-documents-in-mongodb) solution and tried this:

```java
public void updateAvailabilities(Product product){
    UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions();
    options.upsert(true);
    ArrayList<SizeInfos> tmpSizeInfos = product.getSizeRunAvailability();
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpSizeInfos.size(); i++) {
        Document updateSet = new Document();
        updateSet.put("$addToSet", tmpSizeInfos.get(i));
        Document availDoc = new Document();
        availDoc.put("availabilities", updateSet);
        prodCollection.updateOne(eq("matchingHan", helper.getMatchingHan(product.getHan())), availDoc, options);
    }
}
```

But I always get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name availabilities
```

Comment: You've got availDoc and updateSet mixed up. You should doing `updateSet.put("$addToSet", new Document("availabilities", tmpSizeINfos.get(i)))` and passing updateSet as the 2nd arg to the updateOne command.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!